# Can IBM Cloud Free Tier run Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, kubernetes, ibm-cloud, iks

Is it possible to run Wordpress site using IBM Cloud Free Tier account? If so what is overall technical plan i should follow?

Comment: General networking and server admin questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow, unless they directly involve programming or tools used for programming. You may be able to get some help on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com), but please keep in mind [what topics you can post about there](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: The question is too broad. What does mean "run", just start and not crash or serve thousands of users?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can but you will be limited in the architecture you can use. Here is an example of running wordpress on an IBM Cloud Kubernetes Service cluster: https://github.com/IBM/Scalable-WordPress-deployment-on-Kubernetes. This should be able to be deployed on a free tier cluster.